# discord.js Missing Permissions error on .send()

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm stuck on a dumb loop, cannot figure out how to check if my BOT has permission to send messages **in a specific channel**. All I got is this:

```
if (msg.guild.me.hasPermission('SEND_MESSAGES')){
  msg.channel.send('hello!');
}
```

And of course this gives the *Missing Permissions* error since my BOT has permissin to send as Role but not in the channel since **@everyone** is negating permission. So how do I check if my BOT can actually send messages in this specific channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GuildChannel#permissionsFor](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=permissionsFor) should do it.

E.g.

```
msg.channel.permissionsFor(msg.guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES") // returns a boolean
```